# Magento compiler - command line

Tags: php, magento, command-line, compiler-construction

When I click the compiler status inside the "shell" folder by command line in the root of 
my store, it returns that the compiler is enabled so as in admin, however when I check that in the root folder of my Magento site is return the status is disabled !

```
$/var/www/magento# php shell/compiler.php state
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    6764
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
$/var/www/magento# cd shell/
$/var/www/magento/shell# php compiler.php state
Compiler Status:          Enabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    6764
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
```

Although I try to fix this by turning compiler mode off, recompiling, and then turning it back on, I get the same result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "works as designed" (except it's just poorly designed).  Here's the bit of code from `compiler.php` that determines status.

```
$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}
$status = defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabl    ed';
```

the key line is `$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';`.  This path goes **up** one directory from the current directory to find `config.php`.  A PHP shell script's working directory is the one it's **invoked from**, not the one it lives in.  So you you say

```
$/var/www/magento# php shell/compiler.php state
```

the script looks for a file in

```
/var/www/magento/../includes/config.php
```

or

```
/var/www/includes/config.php
```

since it doesn't find one, it assumes a state of disabled.

Comment: Don't really see the difference between the two answers but fair enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit `includes/config.php` and comment out the two `define` lines.  This is all Magento does to enable/disable the compiler.

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/includes/config.php

Code snippet from `shell/compiler.php`

```
$compiler = $this->_getCompiler();
$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}
$status = defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
```

Also I'd recommend just using [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or any other OPCode cache as it will solve the same problem with way less headache.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but it looks like this bug is still present in Magento 1.9.
If you want to be able to check your compiler status from other directories, just modify this line:

```
$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';
```

change to

```
$compilerConfig = dirname(__FILE__).'/../includes/config.php';
```