# php errpr in admin section after shifting magento webstie to new server

Tags: php, image, magento, admin

I shifted my magento website from one server to another. But after shifting I am getting this PHP Fatal error on admin section while front end is working fine except product images are not coming.

I am not able to see any menu, nothing in admin section just an error says.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_Helper_Data' not found in /homepages/27/d155868148/htdocs/frontierair/new/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

This is my path

```
/new/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/helper/Data.php
```

This is the file code

```
<?php  
class Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
?>
```

and here is the XML

```
/new/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/etc/config.xml

<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhelloworld>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld</module>
                    <frontName>adminhelloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhelloworld>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <tutorial_menu translate="title" module="adminhelloworld">
                <title>Service Reviews</title> 
                <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <first_page module="adminhelloworld">
                        <title>Service Reviews</title> 
                        <action>adminhelloworld/index/index</action>
                    </first_page>
                </children>
            </tutorial_menu>
        </menu> 
    </adminhtml>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <adminhelloworld>
                <class>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_Helper</class>
            </adminhelloworld>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

Please help me guys I need to deliver this project today.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not related to the Name as you given TITLE.. PLease modify it.. Is the issue happend only after moving to the new server??

Comment: yes Pavan it is just after moving to new server.

Comment: Did you try by disabling this module and loading the admin page??

Comment: yes I delete config.xml content then it worked.

Comment: So what is  ur required output from this??  or do u want to just eliminate of this error?

Comment: I created a module for admin section.A menu at top "Service Reviews" which shows me some data.I want that menu.Error is coming may be because of config.xml file.

Comment: I have created a module with your config.xml file and I can see "Service Reviews" on top menu with out any issue.

Comment: @PavanKumar I also did the same on my previuos server and it worked there thats why I am asking the question.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if compilation is enabled from admin > system > Tools > compilation.

If you have added module without disabling the compilation, then it may cause such problem.

Clear cache & rerun the compilation process again. Hope this may solve your problem.

To solve display images issue, try these steps:

1. Check if the product has at least one image set to default in admin section.
2. Check if the caching is disabled
3. Check if the media/* is under 777 chmod, if no then you need to grant recursive permission to media folder.
4. If problem still persists, then rename .htaccess file and clear cache and recheck.

Comment: As I go there and enable compilation I got the following error  include_once(/homepages/27/d155868148/htdocs/frontierair/new/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/27/d155868148/htdocs/frontierair/new/app/Mage.php on line 36
 and now I can not go any where.Please help

Comment: Open includes/config.php and comment out the two define function calls:

##define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can disable the compilation through terminal also. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818502/magento-compiler-command-line

Comment: thanks for this Mohit. Now at least I can look something rather than errors. but Also Please solve my question

Comment: Please change /new/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/helper/Data.php

to

/new/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/Helper/Data.php

You are using small case name for folder 'helper' instead of 'Helper'.

Comment: wow man you are just awesome.You did not know how much you helped me.Thanks for this.I am going to accept your answer just have one more point in my question.Why product images are not coming taking default magento image.

Comment: Good Catch Mohit.. I missed this.. ;)

Comment: have you uploaded media/catalog folder to the new server and did reindexing after moving your website to the new server.

Comment: how to reindex it .I have uploaded Media/Catalog folder

Comment: login to admin panel --> go to System -> Index Management.


Click on 'Select All' and then Click on Submit button.

Comment: I have reindexed but images are still not visible.

Comment: what is your first step at least one image ??

Comment: Click on any of the product and edit it.

Click on images tab and check whether it has any image selected with Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail radio buttons.

then save the product and check that product in frontend.